# Hydrology for Tonle Sap lake in Cambodia

Tags: cambodia, hydrology

I am looking for Basins (or Catchments Watersheds) with basic hydraulic parameters such as the upstream downstream relation for the Tonle Sap lake region in Cambodia. I typically use [WWF's HydroBasin level 6](http://www.hydrosheds.org/page/hydrobasins) but since the flow in the Tonle Sap river system changes direction during certain times of the year, I might need a more detailed dataset.